# Site for uploading images for prototyping?

Tags: ios, image, upload, web

I'm currently working on an app that will need to upload images to an image server somewhere, but for prototyping, I was hoping there would be a site out there that already offers their services.

I've checked out imgur's API and they offer a range from 50-200 images per hour, depending on anonymity and pro accounts. I'm just wondering if there are other/better options before I go ahead and move forward with imgur for now.

Thank you!

Riley

Comment: [ImageShack](http://imageshack.com) comes to mind, they have an [API](http://code.google.com/p/imageshackapi/) and a [Request Form](http://stream.imageshack.us/api/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could also use a flickr account, but you need to authorize before of course. http://www.flickr.com/services/api/upload.api.html